# Error on XML Document (4,11)

Tags: c#, xna, isolatedstorage

currently i'm developing window game which using isolate storage to process the information. I'm trying to do it in XML however i meet this problem while trying to generate XML document and read it from it. Here's the code and XML generated.

Part of code:

```
using(IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
{
    using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream =
      new IsolatedStorageFileStream("class.xml", FileMode.Create, file))
    {
        XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
        setting.Indent = true;
        using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, setting))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Student));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, new Student()
            {
                Name = "AhLim"
            });
        }
    }

    using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream =
      new IsolatedStorageFileStream("class.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Student));
        studentA = (Student) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

The Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

The generated XML document :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Student xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Name>AhLim</Name>
</Student>
```

After all, the error as title, XML document error at (4,11) occur on deserialization. I cant figure out the problem as i googled and know the stream issue. Thanks for your all's help

Comment: Is your `Student` object correctly marked as serializable? Is the `Name` property writable? Do you have more than one `Student` node?

Comment: Currently i'm having one node only. I can ensure that the student object is serializable and name is having writable property :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are writing the xml using the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` which is writhing in the wrong encoding, try using the `XmlWriter` you created this will use `utf-8` encoding and `Deserialization` should  work fine

```
using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("class.xml",FileMode.Create,file))
{
     XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
     setting.Indent = true;
     using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, setting))
     {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
         serializer.Serialize(writer, new Student() { Name = "AhLim" });
     }
}
```

`IsolatedStorageFileStream` creates header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

`XmlWriter` creates header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've change the stream to writer and it work fine! Somehow, if i using the stream, it will generate the character with ASCII 65279. I believe that's a comment error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Stupid Microsoft forgot to tell that you student class MUST have a public default constructor. i.e public Student() {}, the promblem will go away.